# json serialization outputting accented character incorrectly, python / django

Tags: python, django, serialization, unicode, tastypie

I have a Django app, using tasypie to serialize some data.

There is a name

```
"Glòria"
```

(with an accented 'o') in the database, but this is not being serialized correctly. In the json produced by tasypie, it comes out as

```
"GlÃ²ria"
```

The serializer class looks like this:

```
import json as simplejson


class PrettyJSONSerializer(Serializer):
    json_indent = 2
    def to_json(self, data, options=None):
        options = options or {}
        data = self.to_simple(data, options)
        return simplejson.dumps(data, cls=json.DjangoJSONEncoder,
            sort_keys=True, ensure_ascii=False, indent=self.json_indent)
```

Changing the attribute on the simplejson.dumps to

```
ensure_ascii=True
```

returns the following:

```
"Gl\u00f2ria"
```

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? If it's Python 2, is the name represented by a `str` or a `unicode` object?

Comment: Python 2.7, its stored as unicode internally, the debugger shows: u'Gl\xf2ria '

Comment: The `"Gl\u00f2ria"` version is actually a valid JSON representation of `Glòria`. Are you sure the problem with `ensure_ascii=False` is with the serializer and not the client?

Comment: I don't see a problem with"Gl\u00f2ria"  but its not what I want to return. I would like to set ensure_ascii=False, and have it output a  ò'' rather than 'Ã²'

Comment: Are you saving the JSON file using the 'utf-8' encoding?

Comment: No file is saved, the data is returned as an HTTP response. The json.dumps() call has a default argument of encoding == 'utf-8'.

Comment: Hmmm. I don't know Django or tastypie, so there might be a proper way to fix this, but FWIW, you can easily convert that Unicode escape to proper Unicode. Eg, `s="this is a Gl\u00f2ria test".decode('unicode-escape');print s,repr(s)` prints `this is a Glòria test u'this is a Gl\xf2ria test'`. At least, it'll print that if your console is set to use utf-8 encoding. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't comment (yet..) so I'm posting a reply. Python 2 isn't exactly fun with encodings.

*GlÃ²ria* is the correct utf-8 encoded representation of the data in bytes. Gl\u00f2ria is Python 2 internal representation of unicode strings. json.dumps returns a python unicode string. What you probably want to do is encode the output of json.dumps in utf8.

```
import json
data = u'Gl\xf2ria'
encoded_data = json.dumps(s, ensure_ascii=False).encode("utf8")
print(encoded_data)
```

prints Glòria.

Edit: Just to make sure

GlÃ²ria = Gl\xc3\xb2ria. Printed with the print statement both should display correctly as Glòria.

Comment: You are right, its maybe a web browser based problem, as using curl on the command line displays it properly.

Comment: Maybe you're familiar with the matter, but in case somebody reading this later isn't: it's necessary to define the content encoding. text/html provides html tags for this, but something like application/json may require adding the encoding to Content-type HTTP headers to display correctly on browsers (*Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8*).